# Python subplot 3 plots in 2x2 matrix (pyramid)

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

i want to plot a subplot as shown in version "a)". 
If i use `plt.subplot2grid` and `colspan=2` i get version "b)" what i don't want.
Here my current code:

```
ax1.subplot2grid((2,2), (0,0))
ax1.plot(m[:,0], m[:,8], color = "0")
ax2.subplot2grid((2,2), (0,1))
ax2.plot(m[:,0], m[:,9], color = "0")
ax3.subplot2grid((2,2), (1,0))
ax3.plot(m[:,0], m[:,10], color = "0", colespan=2)
```

Thanks in advance!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your grid to `(2,4)` and put `colspan=2` on every axis:

```
m = np.array([[0,1],[1,0]])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot2grid((2,4),(0,0), colspan=2)
ax.imshow(m)
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,4),(0,2), colspan=2)
ax1.imshow(m)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((2,4),(1,1), colspan=2)
ax2.imshow(m)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use the axes' [`set_aspect`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect) function to control the shape of the axes. Specifically, in the example you've given, add the line:

```
ax3.set_aspect('equal')
```

to get what you have pictured in (a).